# Getting table size of daily events table in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to use the following code to find the total size of my daily events table (all historical data included):

```
select 
  sum(size_bytes)/pow(10,9) as size
from
  `rayn-deen-app.analytics_317927526`.__TABLES__
where 
  table_id = `rayn-deen-app.analytics_317927526.events_*`
```

this gives the error:

```
Unrecognized name: `rayn-deen-app.analytics_317927526.events_*` at [12:14]
```

Now, my dataset ID is rayn-deen-app.analytics_317927526

My daily events table is : `rayn-deen-app.analytics_317927526.events_*`

P.S - the current version is : `rayn-deen-app.analytics_317927526.events_20240215`, but I have replaced the specific events_20240215 part with events_*, to get historical data as well, not just data for one date.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out myself.

```
SELECT 
  SUM(size_bytes) / POW(10,9) AS total_size_in_gb
FROM (
  SELECT 
    size_bytes 
  FROM 
    `rayn-deen-app.analytics_317927526.__TABLES__` 
  WHERE 
    table_id LIKE 'events_%'
)
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**